# addMouseListener() is undefined for the type JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Recently, I've been learning Java and I keep running into the following error: `this method (*) is undefined for the type(*)`. I solved it once in the past by importing a missing library but in the code below even importing many many libraries did not help.

This error appears because of these 2 lines:

```
     mousepanel.addMouselistener(handler)

            mousepanel.addMouseMotionlistener(handler)
```

I'm trying to make a window to test the `mouselistener` and `mousemotionlistenser`.

Here's my code:

```
    public class Gui extends JFrame{
        private JPanel mousepanel;
        private JLabel statusbar ;
        //Gui
        public Gui() {
            super("the title");

            mousepanel =new JPanel();
            mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            add(mousepanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            statusbar = new JLabel("default");
            add(statusbar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

          HandlerClass   handler = new HandlerClass();
            mousepanel.addMouselistener(handler);
            mousepanel.addMouseMotionlistener(handler);


        }
        private class  HandlerClass implements Mouselistener ,MouseMotionlistener {
            //functions 
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("click");
            }public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("press");
            }public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("release");
            }public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("enter");
                mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("out");
                mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            //functions 
            public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("drag");
            }
            public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("move");
            }




    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are importing the `java.awt.*` classes and not the `javafx.*` classes

Answer (score 3):

Your method name is not correct. You need camelCase method name. For example, use `addMouseListener(handler)` instead of `addMouselistener(handler)`.

**Note:** You should use IDE that will check compile time error.

Comment: You might like to highlight `Mouselistener `, `MouseMotionlistener` and `addMouseMotionlistener` and point out what the OP did wrong as well

Comment: thank you so much , i searched for one hour for the solution and i didn't expect to be syntax error :)

Comment: @IbrahimMagdy, You should use IDE that will check compile time error. As Java method name is long, so it is difficult to spell correctly at initial stage of programming.

Comment: @Masud i'm using eclipse 
which one do you recommend?

Comment: @IbrahimMagdy, Eclipse is fine, but that should have syntax highlight of compiler error.

Comment: @Masud I don't understand what do you mean by "syntax highlight of compile error " ?

Comment: @IbrahimMagdy look into the \@override annotation aswell